# Hide bar button items swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

How can I hide my left bar button item?

In my storyboard I dragged a Navigation Bar onto my View Controller, then a Bar Button Item. Under certain conditions I want to hide the Bar Button Item.

None of this works:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = []
    self.navigationItem.setLeftBarButtonItems([], animated: true)
}
```

Comment: all of them should work, if not, try `self.navigationController.navigationItem`

Comment: This is not relevant probably, but you must call `super` in a `viewDidLoad` implementation.

Comment: matt why must you call super.viewDidLoad

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I dragged a Navigation Bar onto my View Controller

Well, don't! There is a big difference between a navigation controller interface, where you set the `navigationItem`, and a loosey-goosey navigation bar just sitting there in the interface, which is what you have.

Embed your view controller in a UINavigationController and do things the right way. Then setting your `navigationItem` and its properties will work as expected.

Comment: Ah ok, so under what circumstances should you embed in a navigation view controller, and when should you drag one over?

Comment: The previous view controller has been embedded in a navigation controller. Does this mean I need to embed every view controller in a navigation controller to add bar buttons to the Storyboard? Because I cannot add bar button items to the Storyboard if I dont drag a navigation bar onto the VC. Thats how I got in this mess to begin with.

Comment: @toast If the previous v.c. is already embedded in a navigation controller, and you have a push segue from it to this one, then there should automatically be a navigation bar at the top of this one! If not, then just add a _navigation item_ (not a navigation bar) and now you can put bar buttons into that.

Answer (score 1):

You can't access to self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem because you manually drag navigationBar from storyboard. I would suggest to do the following instead:

1. add an IBOutlet of BarButtonItem (eg: barButton) that you created in storyboard
2. barButton.title = ""
3. barButton.isEnable = false

This will hide your BarButtonItem, and you can simply show it back later.